# awk/sed: repeat 1st column for each column

Tags: awk, sed, vim

I am trying to append 1st column to every column as follows.

existing `A B C D E F`

required: `B A C A D A E A F A`

I have tried this for a smaller set of  columns as follows;

```
cat file | awk '{print $2" "$1" "$3" "$1" "$4" "$1}"
```

How to repeat the above for more than 50 columns

Thanks,
Eashwar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using awk:

```bash
$ echo "A B C D E F" | awk '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) printf "%s", $i" "$1" "; printf "\n"}'
B A C A D A E A F A
```

Comment: or `awk '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) printf $i " " $1 " "; print ""}'`

Answer (score 3):

Here's another `awk` solution:

```bash
$ echo 'A B C D E F' | awk '{for(i=2; i<=NF; i++) $i=$i " " $1; sub(/^[^ ]+ /, "")} 1'
B A C A D A E A F A
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'y/ /\n/;s/.*/echo "&" | sed "1h;1d;G"/e;y/\n/ /' file
```

Convert the space between each field into a newline.

Using evaluated substitution, apply a second invocation of sed for each line in the original file and copy/delete the first field and then append the copy to each following field.

Finally, translate all the introduced newlines back to spaces.

Answer (score 1):

If your awk supports multi-char RS, here is another awk solution that doesn't leave leading or trailing space:

```bash
awk -v RS='[[:blank:]]+' 'NR==1 {s=$1; next}
   {printf "%s%s %s", (NR==2?"":" "), $1, s} END {print ""}' file

B A C A D A E A F A
```

Comment: You should mention that requires GNU awk for multi-char RS.

Comment: I will add it though it worked on BSD awk as well.

Comment: There are some other awk variants have picked up on that extension now, I should probably have said "requires an awk such as GNU awk that supports....". I'm extreme;ly surprised to hear there's a BSD awk variant that supports multi-char RS though.

Comment: @EdMorton : why surprised ? the `FreeBSD` source literally listed Arnold's name under an entry in 2019 detailing import of `regex` `RS` from `NetBSD`.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want leading or trailing spaces, and only repeat the value of the first column if there are at least 2 columns:

```
awk 'NF>1{
  s=""
  for(i=2; i<=NF; i++) s=s (i==2 ? "" : OFS) $i OFS $1  
  print s
}' file
```

Output

```
B A C A D A E A F A
```

Answer (score 1):

no-looping `awk` :

```
echo 'A B C D E F' |
```

---

```
gawk '($2 = __$2) gsub(" |$", " " $1 "&") sub(".+" __,_)^_' __='\773'
```

---

```
B A C A D A E A F A
```

---

*slightly shorter version, trading the `gsub()` call for 1 extra trailing space* :

```
mawk2 '($2 = __$2)(OFS = " "$1 " ")^!++NF sub(".+" __,_)' __='\767'
```

**even shorter version**, w/o trailing space, `printf`, loops, or `END { }` section

```
mawk 'gsub(" $|^[^ ]+" (OFS = " "$!_ " "),_, $!++NF)^_'
```

---

```
B A C A D A E A F A
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU `awk` and without trailing newline:

```
echo 'A B C D E F' | awk 'BEGIN{RS=OFS; ORS=""} NR==1{a=$1} NR>1{$1=$1; print s $0 OFS a; s=OFS}'
```

Output:

```
B A C A D A E A F A
```

See: [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, **OFS**, **RS**, **ORS**, **NR**, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

Answer (score 0):

Replace second space by the first column and a temporary char,
Repeat until only one space left,
Replace temp chars with spaces
and move first column to the end.

```
echo 'A B C D E F' | 
  sed -r ':a;s/([^ \r]*)[\r ]([^ ]*)( )/\1\r\2\r\1\r/;ta;s/\r/ /g; s/([^ ]*) (.*)/\2 \1/'
```

When the input is in a `file`, you can use

```
sed -rf <(echo "s/[^ ]* //;";sed -r 's/([^ ]*).*/s#( |$)# \1 #g/' file) file
```